# Write a program for a 2-bit multiplier in RISC V assembly language?

Tags: riscv

I cant understand how can we declare a 2 bit number in RISC V assembly language.

I have written this code, but it is not 2 bit.

.text
    li a0,0x00000002
    li a1,0x00000001
    mul a2, a1, a0

Comment: The program as written multiplies two 2 bit numbers. Are you asking how to make the output wrap so it is also always 2 bits?

Comment: no, i  just wanted to know to declare a 2 bit number in risc v. Well, i got it, its found by prefixing the number with 0b